# Is com.caucho:resin:4.0.66 supposed to work with jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3?

Tags: java, resin

While using `com.caucho:resin:4.0.66` in combination with `jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3`, we run into an NPE which is due to the fact that `com.caucho.amber.manager.AmberPersistenceProvider` implements the newly defined `getProviderUtil()` method on the `javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider` interface to return `null`.

This is the stacktrace of the NPE:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.persistence.Persistence$PersistenceUtilImpl.isLoaded(Persistence.java:145)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:34)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:60)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.resolver.CachingTraversableResolver.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolver.java:82)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConstraintValidation.isReachable(ConstraintValidation.java:241)
... 37 more
```

`javax.persistence.Persistence$PersistenceUtilImpl.isLoaded` (where the NPE occurs) is implemented as follows:

```
for (PersistenceProvider provider : providers) {
    LoadState loadstate = provider.getProviderUtil().isLoadedWithoutReference(entity, attributeName); <<== LINE 145
    if(loadstate == LoadState.LOADED) {
        return true;
    } else if (loadstate == LoadState.NOT_LOADED) {
        return false;
    } // else continue
}
```

In our case, the for-loop iterates over a single `PersistenceProvider`: an instance of `com.caucho.amber.manager.AmberPersistenceProvider`. However, its implementation of `getProviderUtil()` is not properly implemented and returns `null`:

```
@Override
public ProviderUtil getProviderUtil()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

which results in the above NPE.

Has anybody else run into this issue, and if so, is there a workaround?

Comment: According to https://resin-interest.caucho.narkive.com/qetV74FB/jpa-2-1-resin, this is a known issue:

[...] however it does not work due to the Amber implementation, even if unused. This is because AmberPersistenceProvider.getProviderUtil() returns null, and the javax.persistence.PersistenceUtil implementation assumes that the ProviderUtil of all providers are non-null.

I have been able to deregister Amber from the PersistenceProviderResolver using reflection [...]